# PNG Watermark image on GIF does not appear

Tags: php, watermark, gdlib

Adding water mark to jpg/jpeg and png works perfectly file but strange color appear when the same watermark is added to the gif image

[the gif image with watermark is here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CejWD.png)

the strange color here is my png watermark image which is shown like this

my code

```
header('content-type: image/png');

        $image = imagecreatefromgif($pic_url);
        $imageSize = getimagesize($pic_url);

        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('../template/images/logo-watermark2.png');

        $watermark_o_width = imagesx($watermark);
        $watermark_o_height = imagesy($watermark);


        $newWatermarkWidth = ($imageSize[0]-20)/2;
        $newWatermarkHeight = $watermark_o_height * $newWatermarkWidth / $watermark_o_width;

        imagecopyresized($image, $watermark, $imageSize[0]/2 - $newWatermarkWidth/2, $imageSize[1]/2 - $newWatermarkHeight/2, 0, 0, $newWatermarkWidth, $newWatermarkHeight, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

        imagegif($image);

        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Solved this after converting the gif image to a true color image

```
header('content-type: image/png');

        $image = imagecreatefromgif($pic_url);
        $imageSize = getimagesize($pic_url);

        $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('../template/images/logo-watermark2.png');

        $watermark_o_width = imagesx($watermark);
        $watermark_o_height = imagesy($watermark);

        $newWatermarkWidth = ($imageSize[0]-20)/2;
        $newWatermarkHeight = $watermark_o_height * $newWatermarkWidth / $watermark_o_width;

        $tmp = imagecreatetruecolor(imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        $bg = imagecolorallocate($tmp, 255, 255, 255);
        imagefill($tmp, 0, 0, $bg);
        imagecopy($tmp, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, imagesx($image), imagesy($image));
        $image = $tmp;


        imagecopyresized($image, $watermark, $imageSize[0]/2 - $newWatermarkWidth/2, $imageSize[1]/2 - $newWatermarkHeight/2, 0, 0, $newWatermarkWidth, $newWatermarkHeight, imagesx($watermark), imagesy($watermark));

        imagegif($image);

        imagedestroy($image);
        imagedestroy($watermark);
```

Comment: What have you done so far ? Means share your codes

Comment: Here is a good example from PHP. Maybe you can check your code with the code here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/image.examples-watermark.php

Comment: @FabioWidmer I have gone through this already